# Как рандомно получать числа 1 и 2?

Tags: javascript

Доброго времени! Задача — рандомно получать число 1 или 2. К примеру, для игры «монетка» или «угадай в какой руке». `Math.random` в javascript выводит от 0 до 1, и то 1 не выводит. В общем, как получать рандомно 2 числа: 1 или 2? Подскажите, пожалуйста

Comment: Прибавь к полученному результату 1.

Comment: Так:
    
    Math.round(Math.random())+1

Comment: просто надо округлить число

Comment: Тег jquery заюзан верно)

Кстати, а неужели в js нет какого нибудь Random.nextBoolean()?

Answer (score 3):

Как вариант:

```
(Math.random()<.5)+1
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно сразу привести общую формулу для нахождения рандомных чисел в нужном диапазоне:

```
      //min и max соответственно нужное минимальное и максимальное значение: [min,max]
      Math.round(Math.random()*(max-min)+min)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Math.random() * 2 + 1 | 0
```

Кто короче?

Comment: Может на всякий случай объясните почему?

Comment: Решение пересмотрено. Ответ полностью соответствует контексту вопроса, несмотря на его краткость.

Answer (score 0):

Ответ найден

```
var ran = 1 + Math.random()*(3-1);
ran = Math.floor(ran);
```

Comment: а разве **3 - 1** это не 2?

Comment: ну в общем такой код выдает только 1 и 0) работает и ладно

Comment: тысяча и один способ получить рандомно 1 или 2

    Math.ceil(Math.random()*2)

Comment: @eicto, или ноль =)

Comment: @mountpoint а как 0 ? или это не в моем примере ?

Comment: @eicto, если math.random возвращает 0, то результат будет 0

Comment: проверять что ноль и тогда рекурсивно снова запускать функцию

Comment: а такой вариант

   var r = Math.random()>0.5?1:2;

Comment: @savelichalex, *facepalm* а может лучше сразу написать правильно?

Comment: >а такой вариант
>
>    var r = Math.random()>0.5?1:2;

@KoVadim, для более точного распределения надо `>` заменить на `>=`. Тогда будет два равных по длине полуоткрытых интервала [0, 0.5) и [0.5, 1)

Comment: думаю, лучше поменять условие на противоположное - то есть, `var r = Math.random()>0.5?1:2;`.  Ведь делать сравнение на "равно" для вещественных чисел как то плохо. Я специально потестил в nodejs (это от v8 движок) - тех, которые больше 0.5 и равно-больше 0.5 даже при 1000кк попыток (миллиард) чуточку меньше (на 50к).

Comment: @mountpoint как-то пропустил что Math.random 0- inclusive... вероятность правда этого случая 1/(10^62)

Answer (score 0):

Math.round(2 - Math.random())

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log( Math.round( Math.random( ) * 1 ) + 1 );
```

Answer (score -2):

```
function rand(min, max){
    if(max){
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    }else{
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (min + 1));
    }
}
alert(rand(1,2));
```

Answer (score -2):

```
Math.round( Math.random()) + 1
```

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора уточнить вопрос, оставьте комментарий к вопросу, вы можете оставлять любое количество комментариев под своим сообщением, а когда ваша [репутация](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [комментировать сообщения любого пользователя](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @0xFFh Вам показалось

Comment: @0xFFh: этот ответ может быть неверным (можно проголосать "против"), но это ответ.

Answer (score -4):

Для *java* хипстеров:

```
System.out.println((System.nanoTime() & 1) + 1);
```